# Get all children SVG element IDs except specific one using not()

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to get the IDs of SVG elements except for a specific one being passed to the `highlight()` function by combining the `children()` method with the `not()` method singling out the specific ID.

`var allOthers = $(".container").children().not(elem);`

I want to affect all other elements' opacity. I tried this way of singling out a specific element ID out of a whole array of them before on some other pr0ject, but I don't know why it says that allOthers is undefined. Am I doing something wrong here?

I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pjwh9fg2/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not `allOthers` which is undefined, it is `allOthers.style`. You are using vanilla js when you meant to use jQuery, change...

```
allOthers.style.opacity = "0.1";
```

for:

```
allOthers.css("opacity", "0.1");
```